# Putting a device to a specific device state using PoSetPowerState routine

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm writing code to sleep the network and usb ports in vc++ and i have to put them at a specific device state . I came across this routine [PoSetPowerState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)   which is an device driver routine and it has arguments on how to send the device to a specific state .Can this routine be used in an  application to send the particular device to sleep ?

Comment: No, that is a kernel-only function. It cannot be called from user space.

Comment: @andrew medico Is there an alternate way of ,putting the device to sleep from an application ?.